# Why isn't one of the animations active?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have created a bottom sheet as shown in the code below.

Basically, there are two Views, and the animation in one View works,
but the animation in the other is not enabled, and it switches instantly.
(See the comments in the code for where this is happening.)

How can I get the animations to work?

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var isShow = false

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Button(
        "Show Sheet",
        action: {
          self.isShow.toggle()
        }
      )
      .zIndex(0)

      BottomSheet(
        isShow: self.$isShow,
        content: {
          VStack {
            Text("A")
            Text("B")
            Text("C")
          }
          .frame(
            maxWidth: .infinity
          )
          .background(Color(.yellow))
        }
      )
      .zIndex(1)
    }
  }
}

struct ScrimView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {}.frame(
      maxWidth: .infinity,
      maxHeight: .infinity,
      alignment: .bottom
    )
    .background(
      Color(.gray)
    )
  }
}

struct BottomSheet<Content: View>: View {
  private let content: () -> Content
  @Binding var isShow: Bool

  init(
    isShow: Binding<Bool>,
    content: @escaping () -> Content
  ) {
    self._isShow = isShow
    self.content = content
  }

  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
      if self.isShow {
        ScrimView().zIndex(
          0
        )
        .transition(.opacity)            // <-- not work
        .animation(.linear(duration: 5)) // <-- not work

        VStack {
          Button(
            "X",
            action: {
              self.isShow = false
            }
          )
          self.content()
        }
        .zIndex(1)
        .background(Color(.white))
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))  // <-- work
        .animation(.linear(duration: 5))   // <-- work
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a side note - I've seen a few of your questions show the `@main` entry point into the app - don't worry about including this here, if you are using `ContentView`  we assume that's the main view.

Comment: @George_E OK. I deleted the main code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the animation out of the condition and set opacity.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        ScrimView().zIndex( // <-- here work
            0
        )
        .opacity(isShow ? 1 : 0)
        .animation(.linear(duration: 5))
```

---

Another solution is to set the animation to direct main `ZStack`

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        if self.isShow {
            ScrimView().zIndex(0)
            VStack {
                Button(
                    "X",
                    action: {
                        self.isShow = false
                    }
                )
                self.content()
            }
            .zIndex(1)
            .background(Color(.white))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        }
    }.animation(.linear(duration: 5))
}
```

Reason: It does not work because it's direct inside the condition. when you change the toggle it direct reflects with 1 opacity so no effect will shown. your second animation is work because of transition. With your code you can change the toggle inside the animation then it will work or by using the second approach it will also work.

[image]

Comment: I was surprised. It work! Why is it work? Putting it outside of `if` is less readable(Because one is inside `if` and the other is outside `if`.). Is there no choice? Anyway, I approve the answer.

Comment: It does not work because it's direct inside the condition. when you change the toggle it direct reflects with 1 opacity so no effect will show. your second animation is work because of transition. With your code you can change toggle inside the animation then it will work. ``` withAnimation {
                        self.isShow.toggle()
                    }```

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi see my updated answere with if condition.

Comment: Oh! I think the code is more readable now.